React Rive change animation state with prop change
So I am new to Rive and was hoping to add a simple animation to an application.  I have a parent app that is calling the SystemActive component and passing the statemachine via the action prop ("bumpy", "stop").  SystemActive component contains the Rive animation.  However, the animation does not change when the prop changes.  It continues to play the first animation loaded.  Is there a way to make my animation change to the correct state when the prop changes?  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.
Calling Snippet:
<SystemActive riveRef={riveRef} action={startSpeaking? "bumpy" : "stop"} />

Rive Animation:


import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Rive, { useRive, Layout, Fit, Alignment } from "@rive-app/react-canvas";
import System from "../../assets/riv/pte_chat1.riv";

const SystemActive = ({ action, riveRef }) => {
  console.log("Current Action in SystemActive:", action);

  const { RiveComponent } = useRive({
    // src: System,
    // stateMachines: action,
    src: "https://cdn.rive.app/animations/vehicles.riv",
    stateMachines: action,
    autoplay: true,
    fitCanvasToArtboardHeight: true,
    layout: new Layout({
      fit: Fit.Cover,
      alignment: Alignment.Center,
    }),
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ zIndex: 10000, width: "538px", height: "140px" }}>
      <RiveComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SystemActive;



